# Use "it" to describe something in a general tone

Tags: pronouns

I am not a native speaker of English. I wonder whether using "it" to talk about something in a general tone is weird. In the example down below I use "it" to talk about "a tiger", not any specific tiger. I don't know if it is correct or not. Maybe it is grammatically correct but sounds weird.

For example:

> Kid: What is a tiger?
>
> Me: A tiger is a large animal that feeds by hunting other animals. **It** is ferocious and smart..........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, ***it*** can be used like this:

Me: A tiger is a large animal that feeds by hunting other animals. It [the tiger] is ferocious and smart.......

**Because animals are often referred to as it.**

Animals can also be he or she in specific contexts.

**That [female] tiger** is ferocious. **She** doesn't seem to like the other tigers.

**That [male] tiger** is ferocious. **He** doesn't seem to like the other tigers.

Answer (score 1):

That is correct, but if you're talking about tigers in general, it would likely sound better to use "they are ferocious and smart...".

Comment: When you are talking about some group of things in general, it is acceptable and fairly common to single out a non-specific individual (which could be *any* member of the group) and discuss that member (any member) as a representative of the group (*all* members). Exactly like in the question: "A tiger is a large animal that feeds by hunting other animals. It is ferocious and smart."

Comment: I identified it as correct.  The asker said it sounded off, so I suggested an alternative.

Comment: The OP has used the articles super correctly, actually.

Answer (score 1):

Here *what a tiger is* is being described.

> **What is a tiger?**
>
> **A tiger is a large animal that feeds by hunting other animals. It is ferocious and smart.**

A tiger refers to tigers in general but not about a single tiger.?**It** refers to tiger. we use **it** for an animal when we are not particular about its gender.since it is a tiger.  we may use **he** for a tiger  and  she  for a tigress though.

> **A tiger is a large animal.It is ferocious.**

The above sentences mean:

> **Tigers are large animals. They are ferocious**.

I think the above question and the definition  are correct.There is nothing weird about the use of **it** or **a tiger**